# SQLite: Select using LIKE '%?%' with rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to use a select statement to query some data from the database's table .
when i type **=?** the query succeed , but when i use **LIKE %?%** instead i got this error in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ahmed.bus_time_djerba4, PID: 4178
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

and this is my methode that call the database:

```
public String  QuerySQL(String DepartStation,String Destination){

    String result="";

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select distinct * from "+TABLE_Name+" where "+Col_3+" LIKE '%?%' and "+Col_4+" LIKE '%?%'", new String[]{DepartStation,Destination});

    if(c.getCount()==0) {result="Data not found";c.close();}
    else {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            //affichage des lignes
            int ligne = c.getInt(1);
            String Station = c.getString(2);
            String Dest = c.getString(3);
            String hours = c.getString(4);
            result += "\n" + ligne + "|" + Station + "-" + Dest + " " + hours;
        }
        c.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

what is the problem ? please

Comment: I guess the issue is with "select distinct * from "+TABLE_Name+"... distinct * ? 

Change  it to "select * from..."

Comment: no, it works when  i use =? instead of LIKE '%?%'

Comment: You shouldn't be using string concatenation anyway. Try the `query()` method

Comment: Do this, change it to ".. LIKE ?" and change your string as %<Your_String>%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Problem is with the SQL query you have used.
you are giving ? A String which is not acceptable for prepare statements. 
`select distinct * from table_name where X like '%?%';` is not correct because `?` will be a string with double quotation inside a quotation like '%"your_string"%'.

instead write:

```
select distinct * from table_name where X like ?;
```

and for `?` use "`'%your_string%'`". you can apply this to your array of string too.

Comment: You mean ,in my case, i need to do like this:
    DepartStation="%"+DepartStation+"%";
    Destination="%"+Destination+"%";

Comment: yes but you forgot ' befor  and after %  . so DepartStation="'%"+DepartStation+"%'"; Destination="'%"+Destination+"%'"

Comment: it's easy to check. make a new small project and just for the line related to preparedstatement's sql query use '%?%' , you will see that this doesn't work. but if you use ? in the query alone and for the argument used instead of ? you try to use "'%string%'" , you will see that it works. i did the same thing to answer your question

Comment: Actualy your answer can't be because Departstaion and Destination are given by the user so i can't write
Destination="'%"+Destination+"%'"

Comment: if you use '%?%' java will treat it as it is a string for sql hence the `Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.` it has 0 parameters because it doesn't recognize '%?%' as a parameter

Comment: Solved: 
i changed Destination='%'+Destination+'%'; instead of Destination="'%"+Destination+"%'"
thanks

Comment: Thank you @AhmedHaddad your post helped me! +1

Comment: Welcome. it is nice to find my post helped people !

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select distinct * from "+TABLE_Name+" where "+Col_3+" LIKE \"%"+DepartStation+"%\" and "+Col_4+" LIKE \"%"+Destination+"%\"", new String[]{};
```

instead of this:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select distinct * from "+TABLE_Name+" where "+Col_3+" LIKE '%?%' and "+Col_4+" LIKE '%?%'", new String[]{DepartStation,Destination});
```

Comment: I agree with your answer